# In Xpages File are missing in NTF package created using maven(headless designer) through jenkins for automation testing

Tags: maven, jenkins, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I am using maven for xpages to create an NTF package on jenkins server and its working fine but when I open it in domino designer I came to know that some custom controls are missing.Then I had a check on jenkins workspace to make sure that all files are pulled properly and it was upto date. So my question is why headless designer(USING MAVEN) is skiping some custom controls [while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDe3H.png) creating ntf package. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post your maven script

Comment: you will get maven script on this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDe3H.png

Comment: Let us try to turn this into a complete question. To do so you need to edit it and add the pieces that trouble you. SO allows to insert source code (indent 4 spaces). Screenshots of source code don't improve your chances for help. Best would be your maven script and a sample XPage with the trouble. Your question leaves us guessing: are standard controls missing or extension pack controls or your own. Were they in a specific name space etc. The problem needs to be reproducible

Comment: Did you check: https://guedebyte.blog/2016/03/26/building-nsf-using-the-maven-headlessdesigner-plugin-from-openntf/ and https://edm00se.io/xpages/headless-dde-and-jenkins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting all the files related to old build did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

are the .metadata files and .xsp-config files for the custom controls present in the on disk project?

e.g for 1 custom control there should be three files

```
mycustomcontrol.xsp
mycustomcontrol.xsp-config
mycustomcontrol.metadata
```

also what do you mean by 'missing' do you mean that you cannot see them in the list of custom controls? or do you mean that they are imported and you can see them in the NSF but they do not build properly, and therefore you see an errors within XPages about not being able to use them?

is there anything in common about the controls that are missing and the controls that are successful?

Comment: all  .metadata files and .xsp-config files for the custom controls are present in the on disk project like the three file you mentioned.Custom controls are present in on disk project but not in NSF